# Switching on and off integrated GPU

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee, gpu

I have a elitebook 8570w and use it to for both graphically heavy applications as well as normal stuff.
I would like to be able to switch between the dedicated and the intergrated GPU.
I know about bumblebee however it requires me to activate each application with the decicated GPU.
As I'm often doing one of two and it's annoying to have to enter this command each time I run one of my programs.
Is there a way to just make a single switch, which then runs the dedicated GPU until I hit the switch again so that it switches back to the intergated GPU?

Or any way by which I can set which GPU is used based on current usage?

Of course one option would be to make that switch affect the way applications are called, so that they are called with the dedicated gpu if the switch is on. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I have the same issue, but I have a laptop which allows me to turn off the GPU in the BIOS, so that's what I do. (reboot)
As I only need the NVidia for gaming or for driving the HDMI port, I don't care about a reboot en dashing into the BIOS. so it's a "solution" but probably not what you want to hear!  >:)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly find the answer at these two places:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-switch-between-graphics-processors-using-vga-switcheroo-4175437338/
```